# Quey Builder com condição IF em laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Pessoal estou com um problema pra listar determinados resultados de um banco de dados usando laravel, e ja tentei de tudo pra elaborar uma logica pra listar esses resultados e não consigo elaborar essa logica.

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada payments, essa tabela lista determinados pagamento de um relacionamento com outra tabela chamada Campaign, ou seja, a tabela pagamentos são pagamentos feitos para uma determinada campanha.

Eu tenho uma model chamada Campaign onde tenho uma função que faz esse relacionamento buscando os resultados que tenham status = 3, que no caso são pagamento aprovados.

```
public function success_payments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class)->whereStatus('3');
}
```

Essa função retorna resultados da tabela Payment que tenham o campo status = 3, e essa tabela tem mais um campo chamado updated_at do tipo timestamp, e é ai que esta meu problema, eu preciso incluir nessa consulta uma condição que me retorne resultados onde a data atual seja >= o campo updated_at + 30 dias, ou seja eu preciso add 30 dias ao valor do campo updated_at e depois verificar se a data atual é >= uma variavel que tenha esse campo somado de 30 dias, ou se existir outra forma de fazer essa consulta.

O porque dessa condição.

Essa consulta atual retorna pagamento feitos para determinada campanha que tenham o campo status = 3, que no caso é pagamento confirmado, ou seja, ela retorna todos os pagamentos que foram confirmados, porém utilizo o pagseguro como gatway de pagamento e o mesmo, no meu caso, só libera os pagamentos 30 dias apos confirmação.

Por isso preciso exibir para os donos dessas campanhas apenas os pagamentos que ja foram confirmados e que ja se passaram 30 dias.

Se alguém puder me dar uma força agrade imensamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para matar a charada seu where está faltando só mais uma coisinha muito simples:

no controller ou na próprio função do success_payments você pode usar dessa forma

```
Model::with('success_payments')->where(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), '>=',\DB::raw('DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))->get();
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma, caso não de só usar o whereRaw que é para da certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Lucas, eu coloquei o código que postou na função success_payments, eu tirei o codigo que postei aqui inicialmente return e substitui por esse que vc postou. Payment::with('success_payments')->where(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), '>=',\DB::raw('DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))->get();
Porém me retorna um erro: 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2019-12-01' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `payments` where `2019-12-01` >= DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) (View: /var/www/html/projetos/vaquinha/resources/views/admin/withdraw.blade.php)

Comment: Entendi inverte o código e coloca <=

Comment: ou usa o select case para fazer isso que funciona também

Answer (score 0):

Tranquilo Rafael, é só você fazer um outro where :D.

```
public function success_payments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class)->whereStatus('3')->where('updated_at', '>=', date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+30 days")))
}
```

Lembrando que `'data'` é igual ao nome da coluna que esta no seu banco. A função `Date` vai te dar uma data no formato que voce pedir e depois com `strtotime` voce pede quanto quer a mais no caso `"+30 days "`

fiz o teste rodando esse código aqui:

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+30 days"));
```

neste site: [php-online-run](https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler)

e mostrou a data de hoje + 30 dias, então creio que é o que esta pedindo.

```
2019-12-29 07:51:04
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Julio, infelizmente eu percebi que da forma que havia pensado não funcionaria a consulta dessa forma para o que eu preciso, então depois de pensar um pouco mais eu mudei minha pergunta, creio que se for possível a condição que preciso e você puder me ajudar lendo novamente minha pergunta que foi editada, e editando sua resposta, se você tiver uma, eu ficarei muito grato.

Comment: sem problemas, está editado :D

Comment: Nessa consulta que me passou esta retornando resultados onde o valor do campo updated_at é >= a data atual + 30 dias. Não sei se expliquei muito bem, seria quase isso que preciso, na verdade eu não tenho certeza se é possível fazer isso apenas nessa linha da consulta usando o where.
    Mas seria pegar o valor do campo updated_at e somar 30 dias a esse campo, e depois fazer uma comparação se a data atual é >= ao valor do campo updated_at + 30 dias. seria isso

Answer (score 0):

Por que não faz a consulta da data atual menos 30 dias? Vai retornar os pagamentos que foram feitos a 30 dias...

`return $this->hasMany(Payment::class)->whereStatus('3')->where('updated_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-30 days')))`

Mas eu não sei se tua lógica ta correta, pq você ta supondo que o updated_at só vai ser alterado quando o status for alterado para 3, se ele for alterado denovo depois que confirmar o pagamento sua lógica quebra, eu adicionaria um campo com a data de pagamento.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Jedson, eu não tinha pensando nisso que vc falou, pois o status pode mudar algumas vezes mesmo depois que for mudado para 3, esse campo é o único que muda pois ha uma atualização, agora eu  fiquei meio sem saber como implementar essa logica pra retornar esses pagamentos corretamente. Voce disse pra adicinar um campo com a data do pagamento, poderia me dizer como ficaria a logica nesse caso ?

Answer (score 0):

Já trabalhei com conciliação de cartões de crédito com adquirentes, no meu caso foi com Getnet. Acredito que sei o objetivo para estas informações, que no caso é buscar todos os pagamentos já realizados a mais de 30 dias, e conferir se esses pagamentos de fato aconteceram pela PagSeguro.

Neste caso te sugiro a modificar a lógica.

Basicamente seria você construir outra tabela para controlar esses pagamentos.

Então seria: Campaign, Payment, Payment_card e Card_contract

O processo é: se constitui um campanha, e um pagamento que terá status diferenciado, por exemplo: "Aguardando pagamento". Após confirmação de pagamento, ou seja, alteração para status 3. O cliente já pagou esse valor, a "dívida" não é mais dele, agora a dívida é da PagSeguro com você.
Por isso, crie uma outra tabela com os dados desse pagamento. E crie uma tabela de configuração (Card_contract) de seu contrato com a PagSeguro (taxas, datas de pagamentos, etc). Todas vez que modificar a tabela de Payment para status = 3, crie um registro em Payment_card (faça por transaction para não ter inconsistências). Esse registro em Payment_card deve buscar os dados da tabela de contratos.
Depois você pode fazer o relacionamento (hasMany) entre o Payment e Payment_card.
Após você pode criar schedules/jobs para buscar de [EDI-PAGSEGURO](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/docs/api-conciliacao-introducao) os valores já pagos, e realizar a baixa/pagamento na Payment_card.

Exemplo pratico:

Cliente criou a campanha "Black Friday". Totalizou R$ 150,00 com vencimento para dia 10/01/2020.
Neste momento você tem um registro na tabela Campaign e um registro na tabela Payment com status = 1 (Aguardando pagamento).

Chegou o dia do vencimento no dia 10/01/2020, o cliente "paga" a Campaign.
Neste momento você tem um registro na tabela Campaign, registro na tabela Payment com status = 3 (Pagamento aprovado) e um registro na Payment_card.
Esse registro na Payment_card deve possuir alguns dados para você poder "checar" o pagamento no EDI da PagSeguro, como por exmplo: NSU, VALOR, % DA TAXA, etc. Esse dados depende do teu contrato com a PagSeguro, que esta gravado em Card_contract
Então na Payment_card você tem valor original = R$ 150,00, taxa esperada de 3%, valor provavel da tava de R$ 4,50, valor de recebimento R$ 145,50 (orginal - taxa), e numero da NSU, e o vencimento que é 09/02/2020 (10/10/2020 dia de pagamento + 30 dias - janeiro tem 31 dias).
Lembrando que o cliente pode parcelar em 10x... então você terá 10 registros na Payment_card, com suas respectivas datas e valores, até porque conforme a quantidade  de parcelas os valores de taxas na PagSeguro devem mudar. Isso deve estar todo configurado no Card_contract.

Então você terá um job/schedule para buscar todos os dias na EDI da PagSeguro os pagamentos recebidos, com base neste liquidar a tabela Payment_card VERIFICANDO se a PagSeguro te pagou realmente R$ 145,50. Caso contrario o status do Payment_card deve ser de inconsistência na conciliação.

Neste cenário, você saberá o dia em que o cliente tem o vencimento, se já foi pago pelo cliente, se está vencido, se a PagSeguro te pagou, se a PagSeguro te pagou corretamente conforme contrato, etc.
Para isso basta fazer os relacionamentos entres as tabelas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica Eluan. Muito interessante essa dica do EDI, dei uma lida na documentação, não achei muita coisa para fazer a integração, vou fazer uma pesquisa melhor sobre EDI e retorno aqui, como fiz.